# Connect signal of superclass of object

Tags: c++, qt, io, signals-slots

I am working with a `QProcess` and have connected `QProcess`'s signal `readyReadStandardOutput()`.

That process normally spits out data to the console regularly, but the `readyReadStandardOutput()` seems to batch results and only emit every half a minute or so (with all accumulated data).

**I want to access the "live feed" of the `QProcess`** so I thought maybe `QProcess`'s superclass `QIODevice` has some other signals.

**Other solutions instead of using bytesWritten are also welcome**

Now I'm trying to connect `bytesWritten`, but it doesn't let me.

Code:

```
void MainWindow::on_Program_clicked() {
 program= new QProcess(this);
 QString file = "../folder/program/program.exe";
 QString directory = "../folder/program/";
 //qint64 pid;
 program->setWorkingDirectory(directory);
 program->start(file, {""});
 program->waitForStarted();
 connect(program, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readOutput()));


 //ERROR: "QObject::connect: No such signal QProcess::bytesWritten() in ..\---\mainwindow.cpp:45
 connect(program, SIGNAL(bytesWritten()), this, SLOT(myBytesWritten()));

}

void MainWindow::myBytesWritten() {
 QProcess *program = dynamic_cast<QProcess *>(sender());
 QByteArray outData = program->readAll();
 qDebug() << "DEBUG: " + outData;
}

//Works, but only emits a signal every so often, and not every time a new line is written to the console as when I launch the exe normally
void MainWindow::readOutput(){

 QProcess *program = dynamic_cast<QProcess *>(sender());
 QByteArray outData = program->readAll();
 qDebug() << "DEBUG: " + outData;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how `program.exe` outputs to the stdout? It may buffer the stdout. If you could flush it from the subprocess, it might help to make it more interactive.

Comment: @vahancho I do not know how it works internally and I do not have access to the code. When I start it by just double clicking the exe, it outputs a message like every second. But when I do it using the QProcess, it outputs a message with all these messages per second concatenated with "\r\n" in between. So I get the necessary output a lot later than it would normally appear in the console.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the old, deprecated way of connecting signals to slots, you need to also include the parameter list:

```
connect(program, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(int)), this, SLOT(myBytesWritten()));
```

Or you can just use the modern, compile-time Qt5 way:

```
connect(program, &QProcess::bytesWritten, this, &MainWindow::myBytesWritten);
```

Also note that `bytesWritten` fires when a `write` command from YOUR end has succeeded. You don't seem to be sending any input so this will never fire.

Comment: The second way does compile but has the issue that you expected.

This then answers what I asked in the title. I shall create a new question about the live feed.